# digester parser error java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Employee.<init>()

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, sax

I am trying to parse an xml using digester .

My XML

```
<root>
<Employee>
    <Id>1</Id>
    <FirstName>Charles</FirstName>
    <LastName>Madigen</LastName>
    <Location>Louisiana</Location>
    <Skill>Accountant</Skill>
</Employee>
</root>
```

My Employee class

```
public class Employee { 
    private int empId;
    private String fName;
    private String lName;
    private String location;
    private String skill;   
    public Employee(int empId, String fName, String lName, String location,
            String skill) {
        this.empId = empId;
        this.fName = fName;
        this.lName = lName;
        this.location = location;
        this.skill = skill;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee [empId=" + empId + ", fName=" + fName + ", lName="
                + lName + ", location=" + location + ", skill=" + skill + "]";
    }

    public void setEmpId(int empId) {
        this.empId = empId;
    }

    public void setfName(String fName) {
        this.fName = fName;
    }

    public void setlName(String lName) {
        this.lName = lName;
    }

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }
    public void setSkill(String skill) {
        this.skill = skill;
    }

}
```

and my reader class

```
public class CSVtoXMLTransformer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException  {        
        CSVtoXMLTransformer cx=new CSVtoXMLTransformer();
        //cx.transfromer();
        cx.validator();
    }                               

    void validator() throws IOException{                        
        String itemTag = "root/Employee";
        Digester digester = new Digester();
        digester.setValidating(false);
        digester.addObjectCreate(itemTag, "assignment3.Employee");
        digester.addCallMethod(itemTag + "/Id", "setEmpId", 0);
        digester.addCallMethod(itemTag + "/FirstName", "setfName", 0);
        digester.addCallMethod(itemTag + "/LastName", "setlName", 0);
        digester.addCallMethod(itemTag + "/Location", "setLocation", 0);
        digester.addCallMethod(itemTag + "/Skill", "setSkill", 0);   

          File inputFile = new File( "generatedEmployee.xml" );
          Employee emp;
        try {
            emp = (Employee)digester.parse( inputFile );
             System.out.println(emp);
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }                               
    }        
}
```

But while running I am getting this error, Can any one help me on this

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/D:/workspace/poc2/generatedEmployee.xml; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 11; Error at line 2 char 11: assignment3.Employee
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.createSAXException(Digester.java:3363).......
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: assignment3.Employee.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
    ... 17 more.....
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: assignment3.Employee.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
```

Method with signature `assignment3.Employee.<init>()` is not found in your compiled code that's why JVM raised `java.lang.NoSuchMethodException` Exception.

In your class you have created parametrized constructor, when you create parameterized constructor compiler will not create default constructor so you have to implement default constructor as well.

Answer (score 1):

You need a default constructor in your employee class:

```
public class Employee { 
    private int empId;
    private String fName;
    private String lName;
    private String location;
    private String skill;   

    public Employee(){}; //Default constructor

    public Employee(int empId, String fName, String lName, String location,
            String skill) {
        this.empId = empId;
        this.fName = fName;
        this.lName = lName;
        this.location = location;
        this.skill = skill;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee [empId=" + empId + ", fName=" + fName + ", lName="
                + lName + ", location=" + location + ", skill=" + skill + "]";
    }
...
}
```